# Suggestions to reduce red skin tones on Sony A7iii

Tags: sony, sony-alpha, skin-tones, sony-a7ii

Recently moved from Canon to Sony a7iii. My wife has pointed out that a lot of the skin tones look much more red than previously.  Any suggestions on avoiding this?

I've seen there is a slider to adjust white-balance but would prefer not having to manually guess/set this for every photo.

Does the Sony have skin specific settings or picture styles that might help?

Comment: Sample pic? (rest of text)

Comment: Are you using out-of-camera jpegs or a computer-based raw processor?

Comment: "Any suggestions on avoiding this?" Go back to Canon? They've pretty much always had the best straight out of camera skin tones.

Comment: Agree w/ the dupe. Jonathan, if the answer in the duplicated question doesn't help you, please edit your question to explain how it's different. Thanks,